# Python making the residual plot of weighted least squares

Tags: python, seaborn, data-science, linear-regression, least-squares

I was building an ordinary least squares model, and when I saw that there is heteroscedasticity, I used weighted least squares. I want to show that in weighted least squares, heteroscedasticity is in fact not a problem. However, I couldn't find a way to do so. I'm using python and I wanted to build a residual plot using seaborn but it assumes that the model is ordinary least squares.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OLS routine to do weighted least squares as long as you are willing to do a little pre- and post- processing.

In weighted least squares we want to find x to minimise

```
(A*x - b)'*W*(A*x-b)
```

where
A is the model matrix
W the weight matrix
b the data

Suppose that W is diagonal. Let w be the diagonal matrix whose elements are the square roots of the elements of w

Then the objective above is

```
(A*x - b)'*W*(A*x-b)
= (A*x - b)'*w*w*(A*x-b)
= (w*(A*x-b))'*(w*(A*x-b))
```

So if

```
As = w*A 
bs = w*b
```

The objective becomes

```
(As*x-bs)'*(As*x-bs)
```

Which is the objective for OLS given As, bs

The residuals from the OLS will be, given the solution x^

```
rs = bs - As*x^
```

You may well want instead

```
r = b - A*x^ = inv(w)*(bs-As*x^) = inv(w)*rs
```

For example a common case is that the weight matrix W has the inverse variance of the i'th observation as its i'th element on the diagonal. In this case the w matrix has the inverse sd of the i'th observation as its i'th diagonal element, and so the scaling amounts to dividing the i'th row of A, and the i'th element of b, by the sd of the i'th observation.

If your weight matrix is not diagonal (but is strictly positive definite) -- that is you have correlated observation noise as well as heteroscedacity -- you can proceed similarly:

Find upper triangular U so

```
U'*U = W -- this is cholesky decomposition
```

Scale A and B

```
As = U*A
bs = U*b
```

Do the OLS with As and bs, getting x^ and rs

Unscale the residuals

```
r = inv(U)*rs
```